# Overriding views default templates

Tags: views, theming

I'm trying to override default views templates using _theme_process_registry() function.
It's ok, but i've got some trouble when administrator trying to redefine output via views_ui interface. When he creates a new template, he obviously starts from default views templates (views/theme folder), so my templates is lost.

I'm trying to do so:

```
$theme_path = drupal_get_path('module', 'mymodule') . '/theme/default_templates';


/**
 * List all plugins trying to find overriden in our work directory
 */
foreach($plugins as $group_name => $plugins_group) {
    foreach ($plugins_group as $plugin_name => $plugin) {
        if (isset($plugin['theme']) && file_exists($theme_path . '/' .  strtr($plugin['theme'], '_', '-') . '.tpl.php')) {
            $plugins[$group_name][$plugin_name]['theme path'] = $theme_path;
        }
    }
}
```

but single field template doesn't work, coz its hardcoded in view_plugin_display.inc

```
// Field templates aren't registered the normal way...and they're always
// this one, anyhow.
$output .= '<pre>' . check_plain(file_get_contents(drupal_get_path('module', 'views') . '/theme/views-view-field.tpl.php')) . '</pre>';
```

Is anybody know how to fully override views templates to my own module directory?

And the second. I need to create more semantic markup like on  dev.twitter.com.

How to redefine classes_array to get rid of extra classes and div elements?

I'm using drupal 7 and views 3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are the templates that are overriding your templates included in a Theme? Themes always take precedence over modules, so any template in a theme will always override the corresponding template from a module. You may want to consider re-phrasing your question to reference the original issue you are solving with your template files.

If you are referring specifically to Views output with your desire to create semantic markup, I would suggest the [Semantic Views](http://drupal.org/project/semanticviews) module.

Comment: I think semantic views is perfectly okay, thx a lot :)